# FacebookSDK on Android Studio - Using Audience Network

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-audience-network

I've a doubt, I'm working with facebook sdk on Android Studio.
I include it as the documentation says:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral(); //FACEBOOK SDK
}
...
dependencies {
      compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
      compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0'
}
```

But, when I want to use Audience Network, it doesn't appear. This include fails

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
```

Should I have to download the facebook sdk directly and include the audience network jar?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a separate JAR file that you need to include in your `/libs` folder.

1. Download and extract the [Facebook SDK for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android).
2. Under the `AudienceNetwork/bin` folder, copy the `AudienceNetwork.jar` file and place it in the `/libs` folder in your project (you might need to create the directory if it doesn't already exist). Make sure your IDE's UI reflects this change. If you are using Intellij IDEA, right click on the `libs/AudienceNetwork.jar` file and choose 'Add as Library'.
3. If you are not already including it, add the Android v4 Support Library (without resources) to your project, detailed steps can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).

---

[Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/getting-started#ads_sdk)

Comment: Ok, I read that in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/getting-started#ads_sdk, but in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android says that include Audience Network. That is my confusion.

Comment: It's included in the zip with all the SDK stuff.  It is not included in the `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk` dependency.